# Dynamic sql with for loop PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

The following query needs to convert to dynamic SQL without hard code cursor SQL,
using l_query, I do not know the l_query it will come as a parameter.
Inside the loop, I need to execute another insert query ( l_insert_query) that also comes as a parameter.

Your counsel would be much appreciated

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR cust
    IS
        SELECT *
          FROM customer
         WHERE id < 500;
BEGIN
    l_query := 'SELECT * FROM customer  WHERE id < 5';
    l_insert_query :=
        'insert into data ( name, mobile) values ( cust.name,cust.mobile)';

    FOR r_cust IN cust
    LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_insert_query;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: What do you know about the queries?  How are you supposed to programmatically determine that, presumably, "cust.name" in `l_insert_query` is supposed to reference the `name` column from the `customer` table in `l_query`?  If you know nothing about `l_query`, you have no idea how many tables it is querying from or what columns it returns let alone what alias a human might choose for the table name.

Comment: If both `l_query` and  `l_insert_query` is parameter, It seems that your problem involve to semantic analysis of those two parameter. First you should build an algorithm to read those two parameter, check if both is valid SQL query, and `l_query` is suitable to run `l_insert_query` . With that algorithm, you could do whatever `l_insert_query` want to do, using dynamic SQL or maybe only SQL is enough.

Comment: @JustinCave "l_insert_query "and the "l_insert_query" configured in a sperate table, I just want to execute l_query and get set of records loop it and run "l_insert_query" query, the cursor alias and column   are an exact match with the both queries

Comment: So `l_insert_query` will always reference columns as `cust.<<column name>>`?  Why would you design a system this way?  If `l_insert_query` was just `insert into data( name, mobile )` and `l_query` was `select name, mobile from customer where id < 5`, you could at least concatenate the two to generate the `insert` statement dynamically.

Comment: As it stands, you'd probably need to use `dbms_sql` to execute `l_query`, dynamically interrogate the cursor handle to get a list of column names, search `l_insert_query` for any `cust.` references, replace those with bind variables, iterate over the `dbms_sql` cursor handle calling `l_insert_query` and passing in bind variables.  That's a whole pile of rather pointless string manipulation and `dbms_sql` is not a trivial package to work with (and debugging and maintenance are going to be much harder).

Comment: @JustinCave - *"Why would you design a system this way? "* Some solution architects regard the database as an obstacle to be overcome and broken when it can't be ignored.

Answer (score 4):

You *could* do this with a dynamic PL/SQL block:

```
declare
  l_query varchar2(100) := 'SELECT * FROM customer  WHERE id < 5';
  l_insert varchar2(100) := 'insert into data ( name, mobile) values ( cust.name,cust.mobile)';
  l_plsql varchar2(4000);
begin
  l_plsql := '
begin
  for cust in (' || l_query || ') loop
    ' || l_insert || ';
  end loop;
end;
';

  dbms_output.put_line(l_plsql);
  execute immediate l_plsql;
end;
/
```

The `l_plsql` statement ends up as a generated PL/SQL block using the cursor query and insert statement:

```
begin
  for cust in (SELECT * FROM customer  WHERE id < 5) loop
    insert into data ( name, mobile) values ( cust.name,cust.mobile);
  end loop;
end;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=de08056ba8204b4a66f9469eb9e8977f)

But that you *can* do this doesn't mean you should. This is vulnerable to SQL injection, and doesn't seem like a very safe, sensible or efficient way to handle data manipulation in your system.